# why does Gnome/KDE require /usr/bin/X to run?

Tags: gnome, xorg, kde

Is there any good resource about these low level graphic configuration? It is all fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it technically **doesn't** require `/usr/bin/X`, if you leave out the [display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_manager).

Desktop environments, and the graphical programs that comprise them, depend on the package [`x11-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/x11-common) in Ubuntu. That can be installed without the X server itself being installed.

Without an X server, you have no graphical user interface *on the system that doesn't have the X server*. But you can connect to that system remotely, and [run graphical programs on it, making them produce their windows on the remote administration client](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Forwarding_GUI_Programs).

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the wikipedia article for the [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), pecifically the section about [User Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#User_interfaces) as a start. As you said it: X is low level, Gnome/KDE (very roughly speaking) does the actual interface drawing.